# 2017 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

In about 6 hours, [the nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) is scheduled to end. However, in order for the election to proceed, it is necessary to have at least one more candidate running than there are slots. This allows for there to be actual voting phases, so that the community can actually show that they support the candidates who are running. Should there not be enough candidates come 20:00 UTC when the phase change would occur, the nomination phase will instead be extended for another 7 days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless there's enough folks stepping up to take responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: I was going to nominate myself, and I still have 12 minutes until 20:00 UTC. However, the site now says that the nomination goes for another 7 days. Does it mean that if I nominate myself during the next 12 minutes, it will nevertheless run for another week?

Comment: Nominated. It's three minutes to 20:00.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps it does make sense to let the nomination period run for another week; other candidates might still step forward.

Comment: August is not the optimal month for conducting elections, is it?